# How to pass the jsp form data to bean class

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans

Guys im having a jsp form which will take details from person such as name,password,email,mobile and so on.

Now i want to retrieve these form values in servlet using bean class (class with setters and getters) and also without using request.getParameter and useBean and all.

Comment: So you want to get a request parameter without accessing the request parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC framework like struts which will do the request.getParameter() in the background so you don't have to. You just have to make sure that the property name in your bean class and its corresponding element in the jsp has the same name.

Example

jsp page:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName">
```

Your bean

```
public class Person{
 private String firstName;
 public String getFirstName(){
       return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName){
       this.firstName=firstName;
 }
```

}